Diagonalizability of a special matrix involving a parameter k
I'm taking a linear algebra course this semester and we just got our second assignment. I've been working on one particular problem and I think I've made some progress, but I want to make sure my reasoning is correct.
The problem gives a $3\times3$ matrix of the following form:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & k\\
1 & 1 & k\\
1 & 1 & k
\end{pmatrix}
$$
where $k$ is a real number. The question asks: Find all real values of $k$ for which this matrix is diagonalizable.
I found the eigenvalues to be $0$, $0$, and $k+2$. The corresponding eigenvectors are
$$
\begin{pmatrix} -1 \\
1 \\
0
\end{pmatrix}
,\begin{pmatrix}
-k \\
0 \\
1
\end{pmatrix}
,
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
1 \\
1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
During the process of finding the eigenvectors using row reduction, I had to divide by $k+1$ and $k+2$ at one point. This led me to conclude that my final answer should be: The matrix is diagonalizable for all real values of $k$, $k\neq-1$, $k\neq-2$.
My reasoning is that when k is $-1$ or $-2$, the division by $k+1$ or $k+2$ is undefined, which means the eigenvectors can't be found using this method. And if we don't have a full set of linearly independent eigenvectors, the matrix isn't diagonalizable.
Can someone please verify if my approach and conclusion are correct? I want to make sure I haven't overlooked anything.
Thanks in advance,
A linear algebra student who's making progress but still a bit unsure

What happens when $k = -2$?

Call the matrix $A$.Solving $ \det A - \lambda I = 0$ shows that the only possible eigenvalues are $0$ or $k + 2$.
Clearly the vectors you have found are eigenvectors regardless of the value of $k$ since we have
$$ A \begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} = 0$$
$$ A\begin{bmatrix} - k \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} = 0$$
$$ A\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} = (2 + k) \begin{bmatrix}  1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}.$$
In order to prove that the matrix is diagonalisable you only need to prove that these three vectors are linearly independent.
If $k \neq -2$ then this is obvious because eigenvectors for different eigenvalues are linearly independent.
If $k  = -2$ then all the eigenvalues of $A$ are equal to $0$. In this case $A$ being diagonalisable is equivalent to $A = 0$ which we know not to be the case. It follows that $A$ is not diagonalisable when $k = -2$.

If $k\ne-2$, you still have to mention that $\begin{pmatrix}-1\1\0\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}-k\0\1\end{pmatrix}$ are linearly independent.
